# duplicate UUIDs warning on pod install post_install step

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

When running the following in my podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "React"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end
```

I get these warnings:

```
[!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:

XCBuildConfiguration --
XCBuildConfiguration --
PBXBuildFile --
PBXBuildFile --
```

What's causing this?  I noticed that I have some remnant tvOS targets in my schemes - is that a possible cause?

Answer (score 3):

It's caused by duplicate files in different directories.
Sometimes Xcode might make mistake and duplicate files when you move files to another directory.

My **solution** to find these duplicate files,

1. copy error messages to a text file named such as `duplicateUUIDs.txt`
2. get sorted file names and output duplicated items

```sh
grep -E '[a-zA-Z+]+\.(h|m|swift)' -o duplicateUUIDs.txt | sort | uniq -d
```

3. find them in your pod source directory and delete unnecessary files.

**Another method** to find duplicate files

```sh
find . -path ./.git -prune -o -type f -exec basename {} + | sort | uniq -d
```

where `-path ./.git -prune -o` means to exclude `.git` directory when finding

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4370#issuecomment-602368518